# Positioning ul tag inside div to start at the top of the div

Tags: html, css

This is my code and i'm not getting place ul at the top of the div while it is a child element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="border:1px solid black;"> 
    <ul id="ul" style="border:1px solid black; top:0;">
        <li>
        <h2></h2>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div id="page" style="border:1px solid black;"> 
    <ul id="ul" style="margin: 0;  border:1px solid black; top:0;">
        <li>
        <h2>aajja</h2>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's your question after all

Answer (score 1):

Clear the margin on the list

```
ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U8tKK/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use 0 margin for the ul. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/nuhil/5asLb/

```
<div id="page" style="border:1px solid black;"> 
    <ul id="ul" style="border:1px solid black; margin:0;">
        <li>
        <h2></h2>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```